# How can I assign unique sequential order numbers in a REST-API to prevent concurrency issues?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, rest

I'm working on a REST-API for a food ordering app (which will serve as a backend for an Android app). Now I want to assign a unique order number (in sequential form starting from 1) for each order that comes in. Now the issue I'm facing is the function which will assign the order numbers will be called simultaneously for concurrent requests which would result in inconsistent or redundant order numbers.
At first I thought of using a lock based mechanism where a request would get a lock on the order number generation function and all other requests would have to wait until the lock is released, researching on this I found out that I'd have to use a distributed locking system so as to store the state of the lock in the server.
On doing some further research, I came across Apache Kafka which is a queue based system, it is very efficient and would definitely get the job done but the cost to run this on production would be too much.
Another approach was to use the database itself as the queue and assign order numbers based on it. But I think this would be a very time consuming process.

Can anybody help me provide a better solution to this problem?... been struggling on this for quite some time now.

Initially I tried using custom queue in javascript, but the data was geting lost after some time as the server restarted.

Comment: Personally, I would switch to using Guids or a combination of `userId` + `timestamp` or something similar instead of using sequential numbering. But, if you really need the sequential numbering, you could just let the DB handle the generation of the sequential ID number on insert. Using a unique primary key created by MSSQL or MySQL should work.